# Python 'Guess Your Age' Remember Last Integer

Tags: python

I am relatively new to programming with python (actually programming in general). I am making this 'Guess My Age' program that only has one problem:

```
import random
import time
import sys

print("\tAge Guesser!")
print("\t8 tries only!")
name = input("\nWhat's your name? ")


num = 80
min_num = 6
tries = 1

number = random.randint(min_num, num)

print("\nLet me guess... You are", number, "years old?")
guess = input("'Higher', 'Lower', or was it 'Correct'? ")
guess = guess.lower()

while guess != "correct":
    if tries == 8:
        print("\n I guess I couldn't guess your age....")
        print("Closing...")
        time.sleep(5)
        sys.exit()
    elif guess == "higher":
        print("Let me think...")
        min_num = number + 1  #### Here is my trouble - Don't know how to limit max number
        time.sleep(3) # pause
    elif guess == "lower":
        print("Let me think...")
        num = number - 1
        time.sleep(3) # pause
    number = random.randint(min_num, num) #<- Picks new random number
    print("\nLet me guess... You are", number, "years old?")
    guess = input("'Higher', 'Lower', or was it 'Correct'? ")
    guess = guess.lower() #<- Lowercases
    tries += 1 #<- Ups the tries by one


print("\nPfft. Knew it all along.")
time.sleep(10)
```

As you can see, I have 'num' as the max number for the random integer getting picked, but with:

```
elif guess == "higher":
        print("Let me think...")
        min_num = number + 1
```

it can go back up to however high it wants.
I want it to remember the last integer that 'num' was.

Say the program guessed 50 and I said 'Lower'. Then it said 30 and I said 'Higher'

I know I am probably sounding confusing, but please bear with me.

Comment: What is your issue? Your program seems to be working correctly ?

Comment: The program can still guess your age given that it has more tries, as it has a few times, but sometimes it doesn't have enough tries.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please specify what goes wrong and what you expected to happen: `50 -> Lower -> 30 -> Higher`, what goes wrong after that?

Comment: It does correctly remember it , it only checks within the last lowest number upto the last highest number.

Comment: Try to convince me that you *do* need this. What goes wrong as-is?

Comment: 50 > Lower > 30 > Higher > Then it will guess anything above 30.

I need it to remember that it can't go above 50 because it was told that that was too high

Comment: It does remember that, have you even tried your own code? It would never guesss anything above 50 in that particular case.

Comment: The algorithm works. In the first run the algorithm guesses "50", so that `num` is set to 49. In the second run the algorithm guesses "30", so that `min_num` is set to 31. `num` is still 49, so in the next round the guess range is [31,49]

Comment: It seems you are right. Before when running the program it would guess a number higher than the 'num' had specified. I don't know what I changed between then and now? But thank you for the help @.@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a maximum number as well as a minimum number. If they say their age is lower than a given age, you should set that age minus 1 as the maximum.

Of course, you also need to set an initial maximal age.

You might find it more useful to look into recursive functions for this kind of problem. If you define a function which takes min_age, max_age and tries_left as parameters, which comes up with a random number with between min_age and max_age and queries the user, you can then rerun the function  (within itself) with a modified min_age, max_age and tries_left - 1. If tries_left is zero, concede defeat. This way you might get a better understanding of the logical flow.

I have left code out of this answer because, as you are a beginner, you will find it a useful exercise to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you split out your guess into something like

```
max_num = 0
min_num = 0
elif guess =="lower":
    max_num = number
    if min_num!=0:
        number = min_num+(max_num-min_num)/2
    else:
        number = max_num-1
elif guess =="higher":
    min_num = number
    if max_num!=0:
        number=min_num+(max_num-min_num)/2
    else:
        number=min_num+1
```

Sorry it's not meant to be fully rigorous, and its a slight change on the logic you have there, but splitting out your variables so you have a higher and lower cap, that should help a lot?

Cheers

Please let me know if you need more elaboration, and I can try to write out a fully comprehensive version

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though I was wrong in the fact that it did not remember the older integers. Before when running the program it would guess a number higher than the 'num' had specified. I don't know what I changed between then and now? But thank you for the help! @.@

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. 
The only changes I really made:
-Variable names were confusing me, so I changed a couple.
-Note that if you try to mess with it (lower than 5, higher than 3... "Is it 4?" if you say it's higher or lower, you'll get an error).

The first time you set min and max numbers, you do it outside of the loop, so this script does "remember" the last guess and applies it to the new min, max inside of the loop. Each time it runs, the min will get higher or the max will get lower, based on the feedback from when the user checks the guess. If you had stuck the "min_num=6" and the "num=80" inside of the loop, the guesses would never get better.

```
import random
import time
import sys

print("\tAge Guesser!")
print("\t8 tries only!")
name = input("\nWhat's your name? ")


max_num = 10
min_num = 1
tries = 1

guess = random.randint(min_num, max_num)

print("\nLet me guess... You are", guess, "years old?")
check = raw_input("'Higher', 'Lower', or was it 'Correct'? ")
check = check.lower()

while check != "correct":
    if tries == 8:
        print("\n I guess I couldn't guess your age....")
        print("Closing...")
        time.sleep(5)
        sys.exit()
    elif check == "higher":
        print("Let me think...")
        min_num = guess + 1  
        time.sleep(3)  # pause
    elif check == "lower":
        print("Let me think...")
        max_num = guess - 1
        time.sleep(3)  # pause
    guess = random.randint(min_num, max_num)  # <- Picks new random number
    print("\nLet me guess... You are", guess, "years old?")
    check = input("'Higher', 'Lower', or was it 'Correct'? ")
    check = check.lower()  # <- Lowercases
    tries += 1  # <- Ups the tries by one


print("\nPfft. Knew it all along.")
time.sleep(10)
```